# recursive validation of javascript objects

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

Am I doing something wrong here? I'm trying to validate the following `JSON` data using recursion but I'd like to stick down to the level on which an answer has been selected.

**EDIT:**

Meaning that I'd like to check using recursion this JSON object, if Question[index].SelectedAnswers.length > 0 then check the nested question if one of the answer is selected or not.

```
    {
    "AnswerType": "single-choice",
    "Answers": [
        {
            "AnswerValue": null,
            "Description": "Yes",
            "ID": 124804,
            "IsSelected": true,
            "Questions": [
                {
                    "AnswerType": "multi-choice",
                    "Answers": [
                        {
                            "AnswerValue": null,
                            "Description": "Answer text",
                            "ID": 124806,
                            "IsSelected": true,
                            "Questions": [
                                {
                                    "AnswerType": "singleline",
                                    "Answers": [
                                        {
                                            "AnswerValue": null,
                                            "Description": null,
                                            "ID": 124810,
                                            "IsSelected": false,
                                            "Questions": [],
                                            "$$hashKey": "object:230"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "Description": "Question text",
                                    "ID": 37894,
                                    "SelectedAnswers": [],
                                    "$$hashKey": "object:226",
                                    "IsValid": true
                                }
                            ],
                            "$$hashKey": "object:217"
                        }
                    ],
                    "Description": "Question text",
                    "ID": 37892,
                    "SelectedAnswers": [
                        124804
                    ],
                    "$$hashKey": "object:204",
                    "IsValid": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Here I've pasted my functions & extended version of JSON data](http://pastebin.com/E6W6N1Dp) that validates the this structure. I'm trying to make the validation to work up to the level on which an answer is selected

```
$scope.IsQuestionCompleted = function (question) {
    var answer;
    var completed;
    var qAnswer;

    if (question.AnswerType == 'geen') {
        question.IsSelected = true;
        $scope.setAnswer(question, question.Answers[0].ID);
    }

    if (question.AnswerType == 'multiline' || question.AnswerType == 'date' || question.AnswerType == 'singleline') {

        var answer;
        var isAnswerValueSelected;

        for (answer in question.Answers) {
            if (question.Answers[answer].ID == question.SelectedAnswers[0]) {
                if (question.Answers[answer].AnswerValue != null) {
                    isAnswerValueSelected = true;
                } else {
                    isAnswerValueSelected = false;
                }

                if (isAnswerValueSelected && question.SelectedAnswers && question.SelectedAnswers.length > 0)
                    completed = true;
                else
                    if ($rootScope.surveyQuestions.Questions.length > 1)
                        completed = false;
            }
        }
    } else {

        var iAnswer;
        for (iAnswer in question.Answers)
            if (question.Answers[iAnswer].ID == question.SelectedAnswers[0])
                if (question.Answers[iAnswer].Questions.length == 0)
                    return true;

        completed = question.SelectedAnswers && question.SelectedAnswers.length > 0;
    }

    question.IsValid = !completed;

    for (var i = 0; i < question.Answers.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < question.Answers[i].Questions.length; j++) {
            if (!$scope.IsQuestionCompleted(question.Answers[i].Questions[j]))
                completed = false;
        }
    }

    return completed;
}

//And the above function is called by:
$scope.isPageCompleted = function () {
    var isPageCompleted = true;
    var question;

    for (question in $rootScope.surveyQuestions.Questions) {
        if (!$scope.IsQuestionCompleted($rootScope.surveyQuestions.Questions[question]))
            isPageCompleted = false;
    }
    return isPageCompleted;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? If your code isn't working, please explain the problem you're having. What is it supposed to return, what is it returning instead? Are you getting errors?

Comment: @Barmar: My question is how do I make it work; right now I have a problem that on `if (!$scope.IsQuestionCompleted(question.Answers[i].Questions[j]))` line the function gets called again for children even if I don't have any of the answer selected

Comment: What are `$scope`  and `$rootScope`? I don't see anything called `surveyQuestions` in your data. What does it mean for an answer to be selected in it?

Comment: It mean the answer was selected by the user ... ? ( the radio would be checked )

Comment: @Barmar: $scope and $rootScope are some objects from AngularJS. The answer is already set up by another function which works fine. I'm only to validate the entire JSON structure recursively. See if a question has selected answer or not.

Comment: @FMaz008: Yes, the answer is selected by the user and here I'm trying to find the right algorithm to handle it recursively.

Comment: The problem is that you haven't explained what you mean by "validate". What is valid or invalid data? Please edit the question, and add a detailed explanation of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar: Valid is when a question has at least one item in SelectedAnswers[] array, invalid when it doesn't. (edited my question)

Comment: This looks far more complex than it ever needs to be. Why don't you do this at the `ng-model` level of controller ?